# Powershell AzureAD module returns different objects when running from Azure compared to locally

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

I have an Azure Automation Hybrid Worker setup. When I run a simple

`Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "user@domain"`

through the Powershell console on the Hybrid Worker VM I get the proper user object as a response.

But when I run the exact same statement from an Azure Automation runbook on the same Hybrid Worker null is returned.

It's driving me crazy to debug this inconsistency, I'm using the same account to authenticate against Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that the Azure Run as account is setup and the required certificate in PFX is installed on the Hybrid Worker. And also can you trying having only the user name in the searchstring.

Within the runbook you can use the below snippet to connect to AzureAD and then call Get-AzureADUser

```
 $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
 $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
 "Logging into Azure AD....."
 Connect-AzureAD -TenantID $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantID -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId  -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
 Get-AzureADUser -SearchString "membername"
```

Below pane should help you test the run book and show the status of the runbook or any errors you might see.

[image]

Additional [documentation reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account) to create Azure Automation Run As Account.

Hope this helps.